# zoom in and zoom out featured in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I have write this code in my apps:

```
- (IBAction)ZoomInFunction{
@try{
    UITextField *test  = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:indexNews];
    NSLog(@"INDEX NEWS : %d", indexNews);

    UIFont *font = test.font;
    if(test.font == [font fontWithSize:22])
        test.font = [font fontWithSize:22];
    else
        test.font = [font fontWithSize:font.pointSize+2];
}@catch (NSException *err) {
    NSLog(@"Error handler : %@", err);
}
```

}

```
- (IBAction)ZoomOutFunction{
@try {
    UITextField *test  = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:indexNews];

    UIFont *font = test.font;
    if(test.font == [font fontWithSize:14])
        test.font = [font fontWithSize:14];
    else
        test.font = [font fontWithSize:font.pointSize-2];
}@catch (NSException *err) {
    NSLog(@"Error handler : %@", err);
```

}

Sometimes the code run well, but sometimes its show an error says like this.

> Error handler : -[UIView font]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xac70780

Answer (score 1):

Read this Apple Article carefully you will Understand the zoom in and zoom out functionality in IOS.

Here is the code in action:

```
       UITextView *textView = [UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeFontSize:)];
    [textView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

- (void)changeFontSize:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
 {
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    float yourFontSize = gestureRecognizer.scale * FONT_SIZE;
    textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:yourFontSize];
 }
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html

Comment: this isn't what he does. he modifies the font size of a textfield. he isn't zooming everything. so I am unsure if this applies :)

Comment: what you want to zoom textview or what tell me?

Comment: I dont, he is increase/decreasing font sizes. he isn't using scrollviews at all

Comment: yaps, I want to zoom in and zoom out the textView font size..
help me please.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
 self.scrollview.minimumZoomScale=0.5;
 self.scrollview.maximumZoomScale=5.0;
 
 


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.pgmtxtview;     // your textview
}

Comment: how about using button to do that action??
not using scrollview.
@jitendra deore

Comment: Please include the actual answer from that link, Jitendra. If your link dies, this answer gets deleted because it is useless (or it gets deleted before that because the community feels it isn't helpful).  Don't add multiple answers, improve your existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling can be possible on UITextView.  UITextView that is expanding dynamically while typing the text, and scaling as the user pinches the screen(Similar behaviour can be found in TinyPost).

Apply this in viewDidLoad

```
    UITextView *test  = (UITextView *)[self.view viewWithTag:indexNews];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scaleTextView:)];

    [test addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

and apply zoomIn and out on UITextView like this

```
- (void)scaleTextView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestRecognizer{

     CGFloat scale = pinchGestRecognizer.scale;

    createTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:createTextView.font.fontName size:createTextView.font.pointSize*scale];

    [self textViewDidChange:createTextView];       
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

     CGSize textSize = textView.contentSize;

     textView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(textView.frame), CGRectGetMinY(textView.frame), textSize.width, textSize.height); //update the size of the textView  
 }
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: thanks for your response @chandan.
But I want to do that from a button click, not from pinch gesture.

Comment: Hi @ Template09. See my another answer that resolve your problem and would provide a better and error free approach for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have apply it and I got the proper solution for it. This is due to the this following line of code

```
UITextField *test  = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:indexNews];
```

Some time when you fetching UITextView from self.view via viewWithTag:indexNews then this indexNews tag value already assign to other UIView so this line of code fetch a UIView instead of UITextField. So it is not able to call Font method via UIView so it returns error. I have a better solution for it

In your .h file implement an outlet for UITextView

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *fontTextView;
```

In .m file

```
@synthesize fontTextView;

- (IBAction)ZoomInFunction{
    @try{

        UIFont *font = fontTextView.font;
        if(fontTextView.font == [font fontWithSize:22])
            fontTextView.font = [font fontWithSize:22];
        else
            fontTextView.font = [font fontWithSize:font.pointSize+2];
    }@catch (NSException *err) {
        NSLog(@"Error handler : %@", err);
    }

}

- (IBAction)ZoomOutFunction{
    @try {

        UIFont *font = fontTextView.font;
        if(fontTextView.font == [font fontWithSize:14])
            fontTextView.font = [font fontWithSize:14];
        else
            fontTextView.font = [font fontWithSize:font.pointSize-2];
    }@catch (NSException *err) {
        NSLog(@"Error handler : %@", err);

    }
}
```

I hope It works fine for your code. Thanks